# Redirecting page makes link appear after directory

Tags: php

I have a login system which before any page loads or if any interaction occurs after session expired / logged out then it triggers `header("location: ../login.php");` which all works great but i just realized that if i am in `localhost/directory/` and that code kicks off, it brings me to `localhost/directory/login.php`?

My login.php page is at: `localhost/login.php`

Does anyone have a solid solution that can prevent this?

Comment: Just make it `header("location: /login.php");` - that will make it go back to the root directory.

Comment: @ZaynAli Please only improve/approve edits that make improvements to the post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling PHP to `go back one directory, and load "login.php"`. If you take off the `..`, it tells php to go back to the root directory of your project, whatever that may be. So try the following redirection code:

```
header("location: /login.php");
```

This makes it so no matter where you are in the code, it will always go back to the base url of the project, in your case, `http://localhost/`

Comment: Ahh i see! Well that makes sense to me now. Not sure why i decided to use the `../` Will give it a try and hopefully will work! Thanks! :)